# Has operation in Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a some trouble about my own simple android project. I save data pair (key-value), and I dont want to save same data. ( for example: I save the data "Car"- "Blue" once. and then application can not permisson save again same the data.) I wrote already update method but I couldnt use for search & control data repetition. How can I solve ?

Comment: Let the two fields be part of a (composite) primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the combination of the two columns a **Primary Key**
2. You can also use `if else` block along with `SELECT` statement to validate inputs.